# How are objects compared in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there any documentation on how two semi-structured objects are compared in Snowflake? For example, in the following:

```
select
    {'x': 1} < {'a': DATE '2014-01-01'},
    {'x': 1} < {'x': DATE '2014-01-01'},
    {'x': 1} < {'y': DATE '2014-01-01'}
```

I would think if it's allowed at all, then only the 3rd one would be TRUE (which is the opposite of the actual results.

[image]

Comment: Your assumption that it is backwards is based on comparing these values as strings, which they are not.  They are objects.  I'm not sure how Snowflake is actually comparing the values of those objects, though.  What would be the purpose to compare JSON objects in this way?

Comment: It is a good question, because  comparison rules also determine how MIN/MAX/GREATEST/LEAST work for OBJECT data type.

Comment: @MikeWalton I wasn't sure if they were cast to strings or not. Actually there's no indication it is or isn't, I'm just curious how it is currently being done and where it might be documented.

Comment: Tangentially curious: You have a very interesting SO story of comparing JSONs and being a top Django contributor. I'd love to learn more about this background!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not documented you can probably not depend on the current behavior - and I'm not sure it would make sense to define an expected behavior for a case like this.

With that said, the question is intriguing, so I did some research. Apparently the object is sorted in the reverse alphabetical order of the keys (but the keys in each object are sorted alphabetically first).

```sql
select {'x': 1} finding_the_sort_for_objects
union all select {'a': DATE '2014-01-01'}
union all select {'x': DATE '2014-01-01'}
union all select {'x': DATE '2014-01-01'}
union all select {'x': DATE '2014-01-01'}
union all select {'x': DATE '2014-01-02'}
union all select {'x': DATE '2014-01-03'}
union all select {'x': DATE '2014-01-01', 'y': DATE '2014-01-01'}
union all select {'y': DATE '2014-01-01', 'x': DATE '2014-01-01'}
union all select {'y': DATE '2014-01-01', 'x': DATE '2014-01-01', '❄️': DATE '2014-01-01'}
union all select {'y': DATE '2014-01-01', 'x': DATE '2014-01-01', '❄️': DATE '2014-01-01', 'a': DATE '2014-01-01'}
union all select {'y': DATE '2014-01-01'}
union all select {'aa': DATE '2014-01-01'}
union all select {'A': DATE '2014-01-01'}
union all select {'0': DATE '2014-01-01'}
union all select {'❄️': DATE '2014-01-01'}
order by 1
```

[image]

(but please, don't rely on undocumented behavior - and send a feature request if you think there's a sorting order that would make sense to define for objects)

Comment: Could we say that for comparing ARRAYs it  compares individual elements one by one starting from the one with index 0 - based on observation? For `SELECT [1] < [1,1], [1,0] < [1,1],[1,2] < [2,1], [1,2,0] < [1,2,1], [] < [NULL], [NULL] < [0];` all returns true